# Enquiry on primorial numbers and primes

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Does the inequality

$$1 + \dfrac{\log p_{k+1}}{\log N_k} > (\log N_k)^{\dfrac{1}{p_{k+1} -1}}$$

hold for all integers $k\geq 2$, where $N_k$ denotes the $k$-th primorial number $N_k=p_1p_2\cdots p_k$ and $p_j$ the $j$-th prime number?

What I think:

By the prime number theorem, we know that there exists some constant $$1/2 \leq \theta <1$$ such that $$\log N_k = p_k + O({p_{k}^{\theta}\log p_k})$$

and upon invoking this together with Erdos' result that $p_{k+1}$ tends to $p_k$ for large $k$, one notices that the RHS of the inequality converges faster with respect to the LHS, so that if it holds for some $k=k_{0}$, then it holds for all $k\geq k_{0}$. Taking $k_{0} = 2$, we obtain the desired result ?

Comment: If you rewrite the inequality then the question amounts to $\log N_{k+1}>(\log N_k)^{\frac{p_{k+1}}{p_{k+1}-1}}$. This seems believable, at least for $k\gg1$.

Comment: "Erdos' result that $p_{k+1}$ tends to $p_k$ for large $k$" – what? $p_{k+1}-p_k$ certainly does not tend to zero, and if what you mean is that $p_{k+1}/p_k$ tends to one, I think that was known before Erdos.

Comment: I don't think your last display is known. It would be known under the hypothesis that $\zeta(s)\neq 0$ for $\Re s>\theta$, but this hypothesis is far from being proven.

Comment: The answer is probably no. See my response.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, yes i mean $p_{k+1}/p_k$ tends to $1$. And as far as i know, this is due to Erdos (research a certain paper outlining  the Erdos-Selberg dispute).

Comment: @GHfromMO, i don't understand what you mean by the last display is ''far from being proven'', since that's exactly the prime number theorem. Rather, what is not known is the value of $\theta$. (We only know that $1/2 \leq \theta <1$).

Comment: Erdos saw that Selberg's identity could be used to prove the $p_{k+1}/p_k$ result, but the result itself follows from the Prime Number Theorem. I'm imagine Landau knew it.

Comment: @GHfromMO, your answer would imply the reverse inequality in my question for some $k$., which is known to contradict Cramer's conjecture.

Comment: @Communityuser: The fact that $p_{k+1}/p_k$ tends to $1$ follows immediately from $p_k\sim k\log k$, which is just a form of the Prime Number Theorem proven in 1896. What Erdős proved is a stronger statement: there is $0<\theta<1$ such that $p_{k+1}<p_k+p_k^\theta$ for large $k$. Now we know this with $\theta=0.525$.

Comment: @Communityuser: Correction to my previous remark: the existence of $\theta$ was proved by Hoheisel in 1930, not by Erdős.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is probably no. Your inequality implies
$$ \frac{\log p_{k+1}}{\log N_k} > \log\left(1+\frac{\log p_{k+1}}{\log N_k}\right)>\frac{\log\log N_k}{p_{k+1}-1}>\frac{\log\log N_k}{p_{k+1}}.$$
In particular,
$$ p_{k+1}\log p_{k+1}>\theta(p_k)\log\theta(p_k),$$
whence
$$ p_{k+1}>\theta(p_k). $$
By Littlewood's theorem, the right hand side exceeds $p_k+p_k^{1/2}$ infinitely often, while it is widely believed that the left hand side is smaller than $p_k+p_k^{1/3}$ for every large $k$. So, if we believe the last upper bound, there are infinitely many counterexamples. By quoting Littlewood's theorem a bit more precisely, we get a contradiction already by Legendre's conjecture that there is a prime number between any two large consecutive squares.

Comment: Note that your answer would imply the reverse inequality $$1 + \dfrac{\log p_{k+1}}{\log N_k} < (\log N_k)^{\dfrac{1}{p_{k+1} - 1}}$$ for some $k$, which is *known* to be a  contradiction to Cramer's conjecture, see arXiv:1012.3613[math.NT]

Comment: @Communityuser: I think Propositions 3-4 in arXiv:1012.3613 say much the same as me, namely your inequality fails for infinitely many $k$'s if the Cramer conjecture is true.

Comment: would you explain your recent comment ? Because it seems you're saying that the Cramer conjecture implies the falsehood of either inequality ?

Comment: @Communityuser: By Proposition 3, your inequality implies (a slight variant of) $u_k>u_{k+1}$. On the other hand, Proposition 4 says that $u_k>u_{k+1}$ fails for infinitely many $k$'s if Cramer's conjecture holds. (In fact one only needs Legendre's conjecture, which is weaker than Cramer's, as my response explained.)

Comment: in either case, could we just judge the above argument without basing on unproven conjectures ?

Comment: @Communityuser: The point is that, by all likelihood, there are infinitely many $k$'s where your left hand side is smaller than your right hand side, but there also infinitely many $k$'s where your left hand side is bigger than your right hand side. The two sides are oscillating about each other.

Comment: @Communityuser: I have to end this discussion, but: all I proved is that your inequality fails if Legendre's conjecture is true (in particular if the much stronger Cramer's conjecture is true). Proving the same unconditionally, i.e. without assuming any conjecture on the size of $p_{k+1}-p_k$ seems to be difficult (if not impossible) at present.

Comment: i guess in your last comment you are making reference to Cramer and Legendre's conjectures, and as i said above, could we just judge the argument without basing on *unproven* conjectures ? A comment like ''line abc is wrong in the sense that...'' would help.

Comment: I think if you ''end'' this discussion just like that, it will be quite strange. Because i don't think your response would be satisfactory without pointing out a specific flaw in the argument itself, not *only* basing on (i repeat), unproven conjectures.

Comment: @Communityuser: Well, most facts about primes are only conjectured, not proven. Number theory is hard, even if you find this strange. I never claimed to give a complete answer to your question. Others can give a more complete answer now or in the future, so stay tuned.

Comment: @Communityuser: My argument shows that Legendre's conjecture implies the opposite of your inequality for infinitely many $k$'s. There is nothing to judge about it, and the argument does not decide if your inequality is true.

Comment: yes, most *things* in number theory are conjured, but until they are *proven*, they shouldn't be taken authoritatively.

Comment: @Communityuser: Noone took anything authoritavely here. I said "probably" in the beginning of my response, which is a subjective judgement. I believe Legendre's conjecture, as most number theorists do. This is why it is a famous conjecture. Of course it might turn out later that Legendre's conjecture is false.

Comment: i'm referring to my argument. I'm saying could you point out a specific flaw in it ? Like ''line so and so is wrong in the sense that...'' That would really help (and perhaps put an end to this discussion).

Comment: @Communityuser. You did not give any argument. You asked a question, and I gave a partial answer to it. Anyways, I must end here, I have other things to do.

Comment: Yes of course it's a question, in which i gave an argument explaining why i *think* the inequality holds. So i'm saying point out a specific flaw (if you see any) in my reasoning. If you had done that the first time i kindly asked you to do so, probably by now you could have been doing your ''other things''.

Comment: @Communityuser: Well, this site is not about checking other's arguments. It is about asking questions and giving answers.

Comment: of course it's a question as i said above. And i have seen many questions of that kind on this site.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer yet.

As in my comment, we may rewrite the inequality as $\log N_{k+1}>\left(\log N_k\right)^{\frac{p_{k+1}}{p_{k+1}-1}}$. Introduce the function $f_a(x)=\log(ax)-\left(\log a\right)^{\frac{x}{x-1}}$ so that the problem amounts to $f_{N_k}(p_{k+1})>0$. Notice 
$$\frac{d}{dx}f_a(x)=\frac1x+\frac{(\log a)\,a^{\frac{x}{x-1}}}{(x-1)^2}>0$$
(of course $x, a>1$) shows $f_a(x)$ is an increasing function of $x$. That means, once $x$ is large enough we conquer positivity as the OP noted.

I claim a stronger inequality $f_{N_k}(p_k)>0$ which improves $f_{N_k}(p_{k+1})>0$.